# swprintf is not formating just copying the literal format - winegcc

Tags: c, printf, wine

I'm using swprintf to format wide string :

`swprintf(cell, 100, L"Hello %s", L"world");`

but in the buffer , I get "Hello %s" literaly, without substitution.
has some idea why ???
Ime using winegcc to cross compile for windows on ubuntu.

Comment: The `%s` format is for *narrow* character strings, even for [`(s)wprintf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fwprintf). Use `%ls` for wide character strings. This will, by the way, also work with plain `sprintf`. Mismatching format specifier and argument type leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The Microsoft behavior of `%s` in the `wprintf` functions is non-standard. I don't know if winegcc replaces the non-standard versions with standard versions. But `%ls` should work for both the non-standard and standard versions.

Comment: Still, the above comments don't really explain why you have `Hello %s` in the buffer.

Comment: exactly ! no idea at all !

Comment: Mismatching format specifier and argument type leads to *undefined behavior*. If a program have UB then it's ill-formed, and theoretically anything can happen, including the behavior you're seeing.

Comment: With that said, please try to create a proper [mre] to show us. That little code just isn't enough IMO.